# How do I include a JS library without downloading it, if library do not have a CDN?

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup, cdn, htmlunit

I am trying to write a web scraping code that does not need any prior setup.

When I send the code to someone, I want him to be able to copy paste the code and use it right away, without having to manually download any libraries etc.

For jquery and bootstrap, I achieve this by simply using CDN's. But I couldn't find any CDN's for jsoup or htmlunit.

Can I somehow make my code include those libraries automatically, without depending on a directory of the computer it is run on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery and bootstrap are javascript libraries, primarily used for building web pages and such.

jsoup and htmlunit are java libraries, these can be used to build standalone applications.

You are asking about two completely different things here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Should I delete/update the post? And what do I use for javascript/html instead jsoup, htmlunit?

Comment: Maybe delete it, research how to do web scraping with javascript/jquery and go from there. I have never used javascript/jquery for web scraping, but after a quick search I found this library http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/ look's pretty interesting. Try that to get started.

Comment: It do not let me delete it since it is already answered, sorry. I will just accept your answer and move on. Maybe it helps another beginner such as myself.